# Installing ASIHTTPRequest in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, httprequest, asihttprequest

Readers,

I can't seem to find a way to install this framework to xCode 4. Everything that is to find on internet is about xCode 3. Can anyone tell me configure my project properly to include this framework?

Greetings

-Edit:
It has been fixed, by removing everything about GHUnit Testing scripts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you do it under XCode 3, except that the library select is is no longer available  onder the right mouse click. You can find it under clicking on your project -> Build Phases.

Comment: The thing is I never did this before, I added files to my project, and put the required libraries into my build. Doesn't compile!

Comment: What are the error's you are getting because with out these we can only guess what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a quite easy how-to for setting up ASI framework to your project](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions). It should be pretty straightforward, but please do let us know which step is not clear for you, so we can better help you.

Comment: Well, when I add all files to my project, put the libraries needed in my project (via link binary with libraries). It just won't compile at all!

Comment: You mean you get errors compiling ASI code or yours? Post the erros, if possible.